# Mysql query to retrieve products which are classified by sveral filters (properties)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having a problem with constructing the query for the following scenario, without using several subqueries.

Products are classified by some filters like color, size, etc.. Color is a filter group and contains filters which are the actual colors: green, red, blue,..

See IMAGE:
[image: http://s27.postimg.org/9zjvj2dur/mysql_stack2.jpg]

---

Like it's written on the image, is it possible to retrieve products which for example are blue or green, and the size of L, without using sub-queries?

What I came up with are subqueries for each filter group, but that seems very inefficient:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
# colors subquery
WHERE productid IN (SELECT productid FROM myTable 
      WHERE filterid = 1 OR filterid = 2) 
# sizes subquery
AND productid IN (SELECT productid FROM myTable 
      WHERE filterid = 3);
```

(filterid has a unique id number)

Comment: Please give example data in your question along with desired output.  The image does not make sense (for instance, what do the values in the column names mean?).

Comment: The image has been replaced with another one. Colored hints should explain the meaning of the values now.

Comment: In the future please post sample data in a textual form. Pictures are great but impossible to work with. Better yet create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
SELECT productid
  FROM table1
 WHERE filterid IN(1, 2, 3)
 GROUP BY productid
HAVING MAX(filterid IN(1, 2)) = 1
   AND MAX(filterid = 3) = 1
```

Sample output:

```
| PRODUCTID |
|-----------|
|         2 |
```

If you need to return all columns for such products then just join back to your table

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT productid
    FROM table1
   WHERE filterid IN(1, 2, 3)
   GROUP BY productid
  HAVING MAX(filterid IN(1, 2)) = 1
     AND MAX(filterid = 3) = 1
) q JOIN table1 p
    ON q.productid = p.productid;
```

Sample output:

```
| PRODUCTID | FILTERGROUPID | FILTERID |
|-----------|---------------|----------|
|         2 |             1 |        2 |
|         2 |             2 |        3 |
|         2 |             3 |        6 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd05b/14)** demo

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response. I will check the query in the morning. I am not quite sure how this query works as I haven't ever used max this way, but gonna analyze everything.

Comment: You're welcome. Take your time and try it. Now about how it's works. We group by `productid` and for each group we check if any of the rows within a group has `filtered = 1`. If it's true then this boolean expression in MySQL will return 1 (true) which we then use in MAX() function to filter product ids.